# E-Mails via Outlook 2016 not Displaying

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have multiple users running a 32 Bit instance of Outlook 2016 Home and Business. An explicit email (or I should say, a common generated and regular "type of email") does not display at all on the client. It's rather hard to explain, sometimes there is no content, sometimes you forward the email and watch the content display/render, sometimes you copy the internet headers, paste into another blank email and it will populate correctly.

At first, I assumed perhaps a corrupt email, however, other users receive the same email (same headers), and it worked without an issue. The fact that some emails *display* correctly, I thought perhaps it an error with the method they were being generated, again no luck.

The only common denominator I have is all users are on 2016. I **have not** uninstalled Office on these instances and re-installed (as this is an imaged PC, we tend not to perform this), but it may be a requirement. A "quick repair" of the instance has occurred.

Reading up on the community blog/question forums at [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/office-365-outlook-2016-does-not-render-html-email/f8224fdd-6c00-4011-8e7a-301ab3243b6e) I might need to confirm that we're using a 32 Bit version of Outlook, but am fairly confident it is.

I would appreciate your suggestions. The only suggestion apart from 32 Bit (and drivers) was:

- Open Outlook
- Click on File, followed by Options
- Navigate to the Mail section and scroll down to Message Format
- Untick “Reduce message size by removing format information not necessary to display the message”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correction to this issue was not a client-side fix.  [Because HTML was being rendered in Word](https://help.aweber.com/hc/en-us/articles/204030726-Why-Doesn-t-My-HTML-Message-Display-Correctly-in-Outlook-) as their handler we simply needed to contact the provider, and review their code to meet the [requirements of their 'engine' or 'library'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms669985(v=vs.85).aspx).